# Podspec - Linking local Framework

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoapods

My application uses the local framework `/Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework`.
Then I get those error messages:

```
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  someFile.h:10:9: fatal error: 'iTunesLibrary/ITLibrary.h' file not found
- ERROR | [OSX] [xcodebuild]  someFile.h:10:9: fatal error: 'iTunesLibrary/ITLibMediaItem.h' file not found
```

I added the following line to my `podspec`:

```
s.framework = 'iTunesLibrary'
```

But apparently the framework is not found, probably because it's not searching through `/Library/Frameworks/`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. I had to set the  `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` to `/Library/Frameworks/`.

```
s.xcconfig = { 'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '/Library/Frameworks/' }
```